# Footer elements split left and right

Tags: html, css

I've got this code for a footer:

```
<ul>
    <ul class="footer">
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="/newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
                <li><a href="/signin">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
            </ul>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;
}

li {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.right li{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

li a {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It displays the code at the bottom and splits them in the middle. But they are all grouped in the corners. Is there a fix for this? ([SCREENSHOT](http://prntscr.com/cgks3s))

Comment: Fix your HTML first - DIV can not be a child of UL.

Comment: @CBroe 1) It was working before, but it didn't save my code in the IDE I'm using. I'm just looking to see if someone has code that would work for it. 2) Why can't a div be a child of a ul?

Comment: Follow the directions of @CBroe, it is not proper the way you are currently providing your code..

Comment: What exactly do you want the solution to look like? Please provide a description or provide a screenshot.

Comment: @YashJain I want the side farther to the right to be all the way to the right and I don't want them all to be grouped together. So It'll look like this:                      Contact  About  Help____________Newsletter  Sign In  Terms (Except without the underline in the middle)

Comment: @YashJain Similar to Google's main page's footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up your code and regrouped things a bit better for this layout.
The biggest problem was you had the "LI"s "position:fixed". You want to have a wrapper around them which is "position:fixed". 
I included a jsfiddle demo link at the bottom.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
ul.left li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
ul.right li {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
li a {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/help">Help</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><a href="/newsletter">Newsletter</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/NYCguyJason/3ogsjs4t/1/